# extremal points on a manifold intrinsiclly

Tags: geometry, optimization, manifolds, curvature

I am wondering if there is a geometric object for real analytic manifolds that characterizes extremal points of the manifold intrinsically.  For instance, suppose I live in the manifold, can I calculate a geometric quantity on a point by point basis to determine the nature of the points (extremal or not)?  For example, in my minds eye, I imagine this quantity would vanish when evaluated for extremal points.  I would appreciated any words on something like this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by extremal points?

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess I mean generalizations of the ideas of ``saddle points'', and ``hills'' and ``valleys''...  Does that make sense?

Comment: Not as such.  Locally the topology of a manifold is $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there are no "extremal points" (although perhaps you are thinking of manifolds with boundaries?).

Comment: Ah, this is a very extrinsic notion. You're looking at critical points of a particular height function. Now you could pick a generic Morse function on an abstract manifold. For a compact manifold, you'll recover its topology from its critical points, but I wouldn't say those critical points have "intrinsic" meaning.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know what you mean.  Let me try to express the notion I am aiming for another way, with a more empirical analogy.  Please stay with me, i know this seems out of nowhere but it's the only way I can visualize the scenario.  Take a passage from one side of the earth to the other through the center.  If one were to drop through this passage, there is an attractive fixed point at the center of the earth.  This appears to be a higher dimensional analogue of a ''valley'' from before.  Is there a intrinsic geometric way to characterize these types of points?

Comment: At the very least I think you have to have some differentiable structure on your manifold -- given only topological information, as said above, these points will be difficult to find.

Comment: @Scaramouche sure, that's fine.  I just wanted to assume I can taylor expand around each point if I wanted to.  I thought the analyticity implied the smoothness which gave the differentiability property.

Comment: Since anyone could tilt your manifold, the associate heights would shift, so these cannot be intrinsic properties. Think of e.g. a sphere: for a given orientation it has a minimal and a maximal point, but intrinsically it is isotropic.